# Access current ID field to Excel cell

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

[Project Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM4FU.png)
[Project Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMleA.png)

This is a standard Project Management database, when ID number is pressed it goes to Project Details - pic2.

After that I inserted 2 buttons one for creating a folder and Excel button that opens a specific template.

Button one does this:

```
Private Sub Command85_Click()


Const strParent = "F:\2. Prodaja\"
Dim projectID As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim fso As Object
' Get ID from control
projectID = Me.ID
' Full path
strFolder = strParent & projectID
' Create FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Check whether folder exists
If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
    ' If not, create it
    fso.CreateFolder strFolder
End If
' Open it
 Shell "explorer.exe " & strFolder, vbNormalFocus
 End Sub
```

And the Excel button:

```
 Function OpenExcelFromAccess()
 Dim MyXL As Object

Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With MyXL
    .Application.Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open "F:\0. Main\01.Templates\ponuda.xltm"
    .Worksheets("Kupci").ListObjects("Employees__4").Refresh

   Dim EmpID As Integer
   EmpID = ID_Employees

.Worksheets("GlavnaTabela").Cells(3, 25).Value = EmpID

 End With
 End Function
```

<strike>The idea was to copy the ID_Employee number and paste it to cell Y3, but it doesn't give me the current number of ID_Employees, it gives me 0. First button works and creates folders based on ID. My question is how to get ID_employees from Access Form into Excel cell Y3?</strike>

I changed function to Sub and done these changes:

```
Private Sub Command166_Click()

Dim EmpID As Integer
If IsNull(ID_Employees) Then EmpID = 0 Else EmpID = ID_Employees

Set MyXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With MyXL
    .Application.Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open "F:\0. Main\01.Templates\ponuda.xltm"
    .Worksheets("Kupci").ListObjects("Employees__4").Refresh
    .Worksheets("GlavnaTabela").Cells(3, 25).Value = EmpID

 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: First sub has `Me.ID`, second one has `ID_Employees`. -- Be sure to put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.  
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

Comment: Well `ID_Employees` doesnt get a value in your second sub

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution. The issue is solved now.